# How to run React Native on Visual Studio emulator for Android

Tags: windows, react-native, android-emulator

I was using Android studio emulator with expo and in my new job I have to use docker permanently and hyper must be activated. I was able to know that there is an Android emulator for Visual Studio and I installed it except that I do not know how to upload and debug my React Native application on this Microsoft emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have configured settings for "Debug Android" then you can just add  "target": "emulator" in it or first install debugging extension. Please make sure installed visual studio (Android) emulator is running.